# how to format snapshots from firebase to list or set markers for map

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I store firebase data so that I can use it for markers on a googlemap?

```
late CollectionReference vendorLocCollection =  
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendorlocations');
late List vendors = [];

Future <void> populateVendors() async {

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> marker = <MarkerId, Marker> {};  //from dynamic in snapshot to marker

    final _vendorSnapshots = await vendorLocCollection.snapshots();

    _vendorSnapshots.listen((result) {
                                      result.docs.forEach((result) {  //how do i extract the result so i can use
                                                                      // it as marker? :
                                                                    vendors.add(result.data());
                                                                    print(vendors);

                                                                   });
                                      });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing firebase snapshot results and putting markers on Google Maps are two different things.

Step 1: Serialise the data

Since we get the data in JSON format, we first change it to dart data types.
We can use something like this.

```dart
class VendorLocations {
  String uid;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  VendorLocations(this.uid, this.latitude, this.longitude);

}

...

vendors = (result.data() as List)
          .map((e) {
             return VendorLocations(e['uid'], e['latitude'], e['longitude']);
           })
          .toList();
```

Step 2: Put marker on Google Map

Create marker objects from the `vendors` list.

```dart
final markerId = vendors[0].uid; /// or something else

final Marker m = Marker(
  markerId: markerId,
  position: LatLng(
    vendors[0].latitude,
    vendors[0].longitude,
  ),
  /// specify other parameters as needed
);

marker[markerId] = m;

// update UI
```

This creates a new marker. All the markers can be added by running the above code snippet in a loop.

Reference : [google_maps_flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart#L110)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this in one go, like on the fly processing the stream of snapshots to map and and assign marker id? My goal is to display the markers as they move on the map.

Comment: @NinFudj By on the fly, I'm assuming you mean not using the `VendorLocation` class. See what are the requirements for markers (like latitude(double), longitude(double), and id(String)). You have to convert the list of Strings to a list of the values mentioned above. This parsing part has to be done. Now I made a new class for it. But you can skip that and directly parse in the function.

Comment: yes, I use your code to make a sort of service. I'm still not very good with streams and integrating it in the widget tree. I'm slowly getting there hopefully. Thanks for the advice!